# How to get identical font-rendering in Chrome on OSX and Ubuntu

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I'm trying to use chrome in headless mode to do screenshot-comparison testing. I want to take a screenshot of my page, and fail the test if it doesn't perfectly match an existing screenshot.

This is all working perfectly, with the exception of text rendering.

- My tests are running on my local machine on OSX
- My tests are also running on Travis CI on Ubuntu
- I'm rendering everything in `Arial`

The text rendering between OSX and Ubuntu seems to be *very slightly* different, to the extent that the screenshots are no longer 100% identical and the tests fail. All of the other rendered HTML matches perfectly.

Is there any way to make text rendering 100% consistent between the two environments? I don't mind if I need to disable anti-aliasing, or anything like that -- it doesn't matter if the text is blocky, or not perfect, so long as it matches exactly between the two envs so I can reliably detect breaking changes.

I've tried setting:

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: none;
```

But this didn't seem to help.

Is there some way to say, have Chrome use some built-in text renderer rather than relying in any way on the OS? Or is there some other approach I can take here?

Comment: Hm, are the fonts themselves even the same? I mean, are you using identical font files?

Comment: Yep. Using Arial in both environments